# How do I get a random enum?

Tags: solidity

```
    enum Heroes {
        batman,
        superman,
        spiderman
    }
```

```
Heroes hero = uint8(random % 3);
```

**Error:** Type uint8 is not implicitly convertible to expected type enum Heroes.

How do I get a random enum?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this

`Heros hero = Heros(random % 3)`